# Why doesn't my loop work correctly anymore?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a battle system (if you are familiar it should look like between pokemon and fgo) and it worked until I added if (input == "poison || stun || sleep") what's inside doesn't really matter since it's a work in progress but the loops worked like this, you can chose 3 moves and when your input matches an attack or command the move gets executed. This worked fine when the program only needed to match with a1name, a2name, a3name, it asked 3 ainput (attackinput 1,2,3).

I added things like stun, poison and sleep and it worked kinda fine until everything just broke, I tried commenting stun,poison and sleep out but it didn't matter, the reason I think it is broken is because I can only enter 2 aipunts instead of 3 while I could input 3 earlier (refer first lines of code)

Maybe I'm missing something very obvious but I just can't see it. Some help is appreciated.

[The output currently looks like this when using the loop][1]

```
            Console.WriteLine("Turn: " + turn);
            Console.WriteLine("Choose attacks!");
            Console.WriteLine(a1name);
            Console.WriteLine(a1 + " damage");
            Console.WriteLine(a2name);
            Console.WriteLine(a2 + " damage");
            Console.WriteLine(a3name);
            Console.WriteLine(a3 + " damage");
            ainput1 = Console.ReadLine();
            ainput2 = Console.ReadLine();
            ainput3 = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < mmove; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    input = InputA(ainput1, ainput2, ainput3, input, i);
                    if (input == a1name)
                    {
                        damage = a1;
                        Attackmodifiers(damage, modifier);
                        damage = (int)Attackmodifiers(Convert.ToInt32(damage), Convert.ToInt32(modifier));
                        ehp = ehp - damage;
                        Console.WriteLine("used " + a1name);
                    }
                    if (input == a2name)
                    {
                        damage = a2;
                        Attackmodifiers(damage, modifier);
                        damage = (int)Attackmodifiers(Convert.ToInt32(damage), Convert.ToInt32(modifier));
                        ehp = ehp - damage;
                        Console.WriteLine("used " + a2name);
                    }
                    if (input == a3name)
                    {
                        damage = a3;
                        Attackmodifiers(damage, modifier);
                        damage = (int)Attackmodifiers(Convert.ToInt32(damage), Convert.ToInt32(modifier));
                        ehp = ehp - damage;
                        Console.WriteLine("used " + a3name);
                    }
                    if (input == "stun")
                    {
                        stun = stun + 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Stunned!");
                        ehp = ehp - 5;
                    }
                    if (input == "poison")
                    {
                        poison = poison + 3;
                        ehp = ehp - 100;
                    }
                    if (input == "sleep")
                    {
                        sleep = true;
                        ehp = ehp - 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No valid move");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Current enemy hp: " + ehp);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: Use `else if` - currently your "else" works only for the final "if"

Comment: Your program will print "No valid move" for every input that isn't sleep, because the `else` belongs the `if (input == "sleep")`. If the input is e.g. poison, the code inside the poison `if` will be executed, and then, instead of continuing on with the next iteration, it will check if the input is sleep. Short version: you need else-ifs. [Learn more here](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_conditions.php)

Comment: OT curious: this is at least the third time *today* that I have seen this "missing else if" problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what each of the loops is being used for so I could be misunderstanding how it works, but it looks like the issue may be that the inner loop "for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)" is starting at 1 and then finishing at 2 since you have "i < 3". If you are wanting to go around this loop 3 times you will need to change it to either start at 0, or change the end condition to "i <= 3" or "i < 4"

Comment: No, the loop worked perfectly fine before I added equal == ""